# Images aren't shown in category-view (WordPress)

Tags: php, html, image, wordpress

For a few months I now have an wordpress-based weblog for iOS App reviews. (Nearly) All articles start with an image of the app. This images are visible on the main page, but on the category-view those images are hidden or not there. I need this category page to change between iOS and Mac OS Apps and it would be nice if the images would be shown there too.

Main page: http://iapptipps.de/
Category-page: http://iapptipps.de/category/ios/

How can I change it? Is it caused by WordPress or the Theme? Thanks for answers!

the code of categories.php:

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>           
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

And here of content.php (where images are shown):

```
<div class="entry-content">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php the_content( __( 'Continue Reading &rarr;', 'bugis' ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'bugis' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the theme. If you look in your themes folder and look for (I believe) `archives.php`. You'll want to add something like this where you want the image to show up:

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
  the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
```

You can look in your `index.php` file to see how it's set up there, and you could probably just copy and paste the code.

Comment: Hm first, thanks for your answer. But it doesn't seem to work. Maybe because those images aren't a thumbnail (because of a plugin). I'll add the code to the question above.

Comment: If they're not thumbnails, then how are the images showing up on the home page? That would greatly help in figuring out why they're not showing up on another page. It looks like the theme would call in the thumbnails if they were set as such.

Comment: The code in index.php: `<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Right. I got that, you said that the images aren't thumbnails because of a plugin. So I'm wondering, if you're not setting them with a "Featured Image" then what plugin are you using to get the images on the home page?

Comment: That's a plugin I coded myself. It just replaces tags by `<img>` tags. But why is it shown on the main page but not on the category page? It's the same code...

Comment: It is the same code. Basically your category page is pulling in the code from the `content.php` file. So it's literally using the exact same code. If I had to guess I'd say it's somewhere in the what the plugin is doing to the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6292/discussion-between-drp96-and-john)